# Why does milli- mean 1/1000

Tags: history, si-units

I suppose this is also an English question, but I'll ask it here first.

Why does the milli- prefix mean 1/1000 when it sounds so much like million? According to the internet, this dates back to the 18-19th centuries. Did it make more sense back then? Are we stubbornly holding on to meanings from borrowed prefix's languages (such as milli meaning 1000 in Latin)?

Not that I'm qualified in any way to make this kind of statement, but if I were able to rename our unit prefixes, I would shift everything from milli- to femto- down 3 orders of magnitude and eliminate atto-. The resulting pairs would be:

```
thousand-    kilo    (placeholder)
million-     mega    milli
billion-     giga    micro
trillion-    terra   nano
quadrillion- peta    pico
quintillion- exa     femto
sextillion-  zetta   zepto
...
```

Which to me, sounds better. But I suppose I answered my own question by saying that since they are the units everyone uses, social inertia prevents us from changing. Would this be correct?

Comment: Not a physics question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language and not physics.

Comment: @Yos233: Well, in French, "thousand" is "mille". Similar in Latin, as you pointed out. Yes, it's archaic. Your explanation in terms of social inertia is probably correct.

Comment: Hi Yos233, your question is much more appropriate at [ell.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: All prefixes are archaic (and most words).

Comment: Also, "femto-" is derived from Danish _femten_ "fifteen", so it wouldn't make sense to bump that down from $10^{-15}$ to $10^{-18}$.

Answer (score 2):

mille is from Latin [mille](http://www.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/lookup.pl?stem=mille&ending=), which means one thousand. so, it's perfectly fine as a prefix for 1/1000.

kilo is from Greeg [χίλιοι](https://www.teknia.com/greek-dictionary/chilioi), also thousand. so, both milli and kilo are in their places